# Change terminal tab name dynamically in mac

Tags: bash, terminal

Is it possible to change tab name dynamically in mac terminal?

Default appearance "bash" changes to "user@server" when I use ssh.
Like this behavior I want to change tab name according current directory or type of shell.

Comment: isn't it, what you are looking for? - http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20060502160527780

Comment: @OlegSKleshchook That's exactly what he's looking for.

Comment: @OlegSKleshchook Thank you for your reply. This information seemed exactly right for me, but when I use the settitle function, it doesn't change tab name but left side of input line. (I don't know the right name of it.) Like  "\e]2;/Users/username\e]1;/Users/usernameMacAir:username$". Maybe the Information is no more valid.